# angular test error TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: angular, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, angular-test

When I try to assign a value to property of `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement`it gives me error.

```
fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.clientWidth = 4501;
```

I checked in the debugger and `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.clientWidth` exist and its not `undefined` or `null`.

#### error in chrome-luncher

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'clientWidth' of object '[object HTMLDivElement]'
        at Object.<anonymous> Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/udc-spet-experiment/pre-commit-keywords/shepherd/src/app/shared/components/ellipsis-overflow/ellipsis-overflow.component.spec.ts:67:51)
...
Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/udc-spet-experiment/pre-commit-keywords/shepherd/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:141:1)
        at Object.<anonymous> Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/udc-spet-experiment/pre-commit-keywords/shepherd/node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:104:1)
```

#### Error in phantomjs-luncher

```
TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js (line 14691)
    http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:14691:43
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:12951:31
    onInvoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:136846:45
```

Comment: What is the code you are trying to test?

Comment: Its just a regular component which have elementRef and in a method I am checking its stype property to perform some action

Comment: As the error says, it is a readonly property. You can’t assign a new value. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth

Comment: is there anyway I can change its value while testing. I tried to mock it bit as it does not have a setter and getter mock did not able to execute `spyOnProperty(div.nativeElement, 'clientWidth', 'get').and.returnValue(1400);`